# How to write a custom on clause in a Sequelize join

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a query with multiple joins, and in one specific I want to add one on clause that access information of a previous model of the query.

On the where clause of the include of CircleStockItems I need something like CircleStockItems.circle_id = CircleStock.circle_id

Is there any way to do that?

I already have an association between the models, but I need the querys to be little more specific.

````
    CircleStock.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: StockItems,
                required: true,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: CircleStockItems,
                        where: {
                            replacement: {
                                [Op.not]: 'Familiar'
                            }
                        },
                        required: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have this solution
sequelize.literal ('CircleStock.circle_id = StockItem-> CircleStockItem.circle_id').
Remember that sequelize uses aliases for your tables, so you have to put that inside the literal.
see you in next question